# Pythonic Nested for - loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, for-loop, pytorch

I am working on this code where I have nested for loops. `a_list` and `b_list` are list of tuples, where each tuple is made up of two tensors `[(tens1, tens2), ...]`. I am trying to compute the similarity of every `tens1` in `a_list` to every `tens1` in `b_list`. Below is the code I have. And the nested loop appears to be a bottleneck. Is there a better way(pythonic) that I can re-write the loops?

```
a2b= defaultdict(dict)
b2a= defaultdict(dict)
ab_sim = []

for a, vec_a in a_list:
    for b, vec_b in b_list:
        # Ignore combination if the first element in both a and b are same
        if a[0] == b[0]:
            continue
        # Calculate cosine similarity of combination
        sim = self.calculate_similarity(vec_a, vec_b )
        a2b[a][b] = sim
        b2a[b][a] = sim
        ab_sim.append(sim)
```

The `calculate_similarity` is just a method computing cosine similarity. `a_list` and `b_list` could be of any size. I have `b2a` and `a2b` because I need them for other computations.

Comment: If you actually need the full n×m matrix of all cosine similarities, I don't think there's any way around computing all of them. If you could edit your question to explain _why_ you need all these cosine similarities, maybe we could avoid an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Do you realize you are actually comparing the second tensor? The first is being stored into `a` and the second into `vec_a`, same for `b` and `vec_b`. And you are comparing `vec_a` and `vec_b`. If you expected `a` and `b` to be indexes, you need to use `enumerate`.

Comment: As a small optimization, you don't necessarily need both `a2b` and `b2a`, if you store them in one dict with sorted tuple keys.

Comment: @Adirio We don't know the shape of `a_list`/`b_list` here, they could already be indices.

Comment: So I am trying to compute the cosine similarity of sentence representations between two languages. I have `a_list` and `b_list` is a list of tuples where each tuple contains the (sentence, embedding_representation).

Comment: @AKX He stated that they are tuples of two tensors. And now with the comment we have further info.

Comment: If the tuples are sentence and embedding representation, `a` is the sentence and `vec_a` the embedding representation (same for `b` and `vec_b`) and thus `a[0] == b[0]` is just comparing the first character of the sentences. Right?

Comment: @Adirio you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
a2b = {a: {b: self.calculate_similarity(vec_a, vec_b )
       for (b, vec_b) in b_list if a[0] != b[0]} for (a, vec_a) in a_list}
```

Comment: This still uses two nested loops but I dont think we can optimize any further.

Comment: @JesujobaALABI indeed the previous dict comprehension was wrong, can you check now? should be correct this time

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`product` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import product
result = {(a,b): self.calculate_similarity(vec_a, vec_b) 
          if a[0] != b[0] else 1 
          for ((a, vec_a) ,(b, vec_b)) in product(a_list, b_list)}
```

Note that you get one dictionary with tuples index, instead of two redundant dictionaries.

EDITED: to get those two dictionaries back, you can use dict comprehension:

```
a2b = {a: {_b:v for (_a,_b), v in result.items() if _a==a} for (a,b) in result.keys()}
b2a = {b: {_a:v for (_a,_b), v in result.items() if _b==b} for (a,b) in result.keys()}
```

to get the list of similarity values, you can use `ab_sim = list(result.values())`

Comment: Nice @Itamar! the dictionaries I have aren't redundant. I use them for other computations I decided not to include here

Comment: They are redundant, since they hold the same information. You could use another data structure - I would advise you to explore, for example, a pandas dataframe/series with a multi-index: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html.

Comment: Nevertheless, I edited my question to show how you could get the two dictionaries back from the joint one, if you prefer that structure.

Comment: I need to get the `sim`(similarity) into a list such as `ab_sim.append(sim)`. Do I need a separate loop for that.

Comment: Not really, that list is just `ab_sim = list(result.values())`

Comment: When I tried the sample code above, I got the error `NameError: name 'd' is not defined` that is d was not defined at any point.

Comment: That's just a typo. Fixed it. In the future, feel free to suggest such an edit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most natural way to store this information is in a Matrix

```py
from random import random
import numpy as np
n=3
a=[ (n*np.random.rand(n)//1, n*np.random.rand(n)//1) for _ in range(3) ]
b=[ (n*np.random.rand(n)//1, n*np.random.rand(n)//1) for _ in range(3) ]


similarity = lambda x,y: np.dot(x, y)/(np.linalg.norm(x)*np.linalg.norm(y))

sim_matrix = [[ similarity(x,y) if x[0]!=y[0] else np.inf for y,_ in b  ] for x,_ in a]

print(*sim_matrix, sep="\n")
```

Complete code.
 [image]

Comment: But I add the important code because the other code is just for mocking data he already have in their problema still I will update that

Comment: Thanks; I didn't delete the answer outright because you clearly had the important line in your answer. It was just a pity that you provided wider context as an image. The output produced is also just text, by the way, an image of the output just doesn't add any useful information.